# How do I load pico css from node_modules in a svelte-kit app?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

Installed with `$ npm install @picocss/pico -D`

in rollup.config.js:

```
import css from "rollup-plugin-css-only";


...
    plugins: [
        css({ output: "static/bundle.css" }),
    ],
```

In ./routes/__layout.svelte I have:

```
<script>
    import "../../node_modules/@picocss/pico/css/pico.min.css";

</script>
```

Just get error in UI, and no css /bundle.css exists.

Answer (score 8):

I was just working with it today.  I tried this:

```
<script>
  import "@picocss/pico/css/pico.min.css";
</script>
```

I didn't get any errors with it, but didn't try anything beyond that.

In my case, I import from the CDN in the original HTML and it worked fine.

Answer (score 6):

I just imported like [this](https://github.com/Leftium/multi-search/blob/b1071f26926afe752b2c92593cfde1b4c0d06681/src/routes/%2Bpage.svelte#L2) in +page.svelte:

```
<script>
    import '@picocss/pico'
</script>
```

You can see the linked code in action here: https://m.leftium.com/

I haven't tried importing from +layout.svelte, but I think that would work, too.

---

There is a [Github issue comment](https://github.com/picocss/pico/issues/201#issuecomment-1398004719) that explains how to integrate Pico CSS with SvelteKit even more thoroughly:

> Pico depends on `main`, `footer`, `header` being direct children of `body` for certain layouts, but that's not possible with sveltekit if you are doing it right.
>
> However, pico has a `$semantic-root-element` variable that you can set as this element: `<div style="display: contents">%sveltekit.body%</div>`. So far this has fixed that for me but I haven't tried everything.
>
> I did it like this.
>
> ```
> <!-- app.html -->
> <div id="pico-root" style="display: contents">%sveltekit.body%</div>
> ```
>
> ```
> // variables.scss
> $semantic-root-element: "div#pico-root"
>
> // OR whever you import pico
> $semantic-root-element: "div#pico-root"
> @import '@picocss/pico/scss/pico';
> ```